# Combine multiple auths with passport, express & NodeJS

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to combine a `LinkedInStrategy` with an existing `LocalStrategy` (user is already authenticated).

Here is the example from passport docs :

```
schema.statics.passportLinkedInStrategy = function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    process.nextTick(function () {
        // To keep the example simple, the user's LinkedIn profile is returned to
        // represent the logged-in user.  In a typical application, you would want
        // to associate the LinkedIn account with a user record in your database,
        // and return that user instead.
        return done(null, profile);
    });
};
```

Problem is I don't have access to `req.user` to check the existing session in this callback.

Any idea on how I could/should do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the section titled "Association in Verify Callback" in the [Authorize](http://passportjs.org/guide/authorize/) chapter of the guide.

There is a `passReqToCallback` option that you can set, which will pass `req` as the first argument to the verify callback.

Comment: Do you know how I can handle a situation where the user first signs up with their social network, then logs out, then logs in with a local account, and connects with the same social network account previously logged in with. In this situation I'm left with two rows and the social network login doesn't login to the local account, how ever the local account shows it is connected to that social media platform.